# When modifying a file, is it always necessary to rewrite the entire file?

Tags: c#, file-io

When modifying a file, is it always necessary to rewrite the entire file or is it possible to find and change some small part of a file without having to rewrite the whole thing?

Comment: That depends. How would you like to modify the file?

Comment: Well, for what I'm actually doing right now I probably would need to rewrite the entire file because I have a search and replace routine that I'm using to remove characters throughout the file.  However, I am just wondering if it even is possible to modify a section of a file without actually rewriting the whole thing.

Comment: And also depends on the filesystem.

Comment: But maybe you meant what method do I want to modify the file by rather than what I'm actually doing to the file, in which case I'd say I don't have a preference as long as it's easily done in c#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're not inserting or deleting data, then you don't need to rewrite the file.  You will be replacing existing bytes with new values, or appending to the file.

If you need to insert or delete, you only need to rewrite the file from that point onwards.  The only time you would need to rewrite the entire file is if you are inserting bytes at the beginning.

It's okay to open a file with both read and write permissions.  That way you can search the file for whatever you're looking for, and once you have the position you can seek to it (from memory, the write pointer is separate from the read pointer) and overwrite data to your heart's content =)

Comment: As I suspected, it probably makes more sense in my scenario to just rewrite the entire file since I'm removing characters throughout but this is great to know.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you're not changing the *length* of the data, you can always just seek to the appropriate position in the file, and write a new set of bytes. This replaces whatever bytes where originally there.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways:

- when you use `StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter` it will delete the data from file.
- To change only, you can store the file data in a `List<string>`. This works nice for me:

  ```
  List<string> lines_list = new List<string>();
  int file_l = 0

  StreamReader sr_temp = new StreamReader(_path);
  string line;

  while ((line = sr_temp.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
       lines_list.Add(line);
       file_l++;
  }

  sr_temp.Close();
  StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(_path);
  for (int i = 0; i < file_l; i++)
  {
        sw.WriteLine(lines_list[i]);
  }

  //here you add some data
  sw.Close();
  ```

Comment: Thanks John, but the issue is that the files are very large so I'm looking for something that doesn't require me to load the entire file into memory at once.  Also, even though you are not modifying data here you are still re-writing it which is what I was wondering if I could avoid.